# Trouble migrating from JRun related code to Tomcat - ColdFusion 8 to ColdFusion 2016

Tags: java, tomcat, coldfusion, jrun

We are trying to update from ColdFusion 8 to ColdFusion 2016 and having some issues migrating some custom Java Services that were built long ago by someone else. To facilitate ColdFusion booting/running/talking to the Services, they were written in Java and used JRun as a dependency.

I believe the `jrunx.kernel.ServiceMBean` interface is first extended to define any function calls that ColdFusion will have access to invoke (i.e. API access from ColdFusion->Java).

```
public interface MyMBean
  extends ServiceMBean {

    /**
     * Adds a Request object to the RequestList
     */
    public boolean addRequest(String destination, String body, etc.);

    // etc.
}
```

Then, this interface is implemented by extending `jrunx.kernel.ServiceAdapter` and implementing the `MyMBean` interface above and `java.lang.Runnable`. I believe this is what "makes the code a service" that ColdFusion can run/talk to and then proceeds to implement the custom code (including the API calls defined above, various thread management, etc.), plus implements the Service-oriented methods for things like `start()` and `stop()` when ColdFusion starts/stops the service that presumably `ServiceMBean` or `ServiceAdapter` require.

```
/**
 * Main class
 */
public class MyService extends ServiceAdapter
    implements MyMBean, Runnable {

    // Declare various custom member variables

    /**
     * Invoked as soon as this class is called
     */
    public void init() { ... }

    /**
     * Invoked when this service is started
     */
    public void start() { ... }

    /**
     * Invoked when this service is stopped
     */
    public void stop() { ... } 

    /**
     * Run the service
     */
    public void run() { ... }

    // Custom functions, etc.
}
```

Once compiled, the `MyPackage.jar` file was placed in `C:\ColdFusion8\runtime\lib\` and then it's registered with `C:\ColdFusion8\runtime\servers\coldfusion\SERVER-INF\jrun.xml` to tell ColdFusion to boot the service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jrun-server PUBLIC "-//Macromedia, Inc.//DTD jrun-server 4.0//EN" "http://jrun.macromedia.com/dtds/jrun-server.dtd">
<jrun-server>

    <!-- Various ColdFusion Core Services -->
    <!-- ...etc --->

    <!-- Register MyService --->
    <service class="jrunx.MyPackage.MyService" name="MyService">
        <attribute name="bindToJNDI">true</attribute>
        <attribute name="activeHandlerThreads">25</attribute>
        <attribute name="maxHandlerThreads">1000</attribute>
        <attribute name="minHandlerThreads">20</attribute>
        <attribute name="threadWaitTimeout">180</attribute>
        <attribute name="timeout">600</attribute>
    </service>

</jrun-server>
```

To allow ColdFusion to "invoke the API calls" exposed by the `ServiceMBean` implementation above, we'd use simple code such as:

```
<cfset scheduler = initContext.lookup("jrun:service/SchedulerService")> 
<cfset schedulerRoot = XmlParse(scheduler.getServerStatus())>
```

It's our understanding that while ColdFusion 8 was based on JRun, it has been dropped in favor of Tomcat, so our expectation is that we'll need to update the Java code (namely the JRun Service interface declarations for `ServiceMBean` and `ServiceAdapter`) to be compatible with an equivalent Tomcat services. Then finally, we'll need to find a new way to register it with ColdFusion 2016 (I suspect within Tomcat's `C:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\runtime\conf\servers.xml` or `C:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\runtime\conf\web.xml`?).

If it's relevant, there are 3 implementations abstracted as "MyService" above:
1. A "DirectoryWatcherService" - watches a folder for files to appear and then invokes ColdFusion to do something with it
2. A "SchedulerService" - watches a database for a scheduled date/time to pass and then invokes ColdFusion to do something with it
3. A "GatewayService" - allows ColdFusion to send it a message to deliver over a persistent TCP connection to a 3rd party service. It also listens for inbound requests from the gateway and then invokes ColdFusion to do something with the data.

Comment: What did you do with these classes?

Comment: We are creating a public class that extends from ServiceAdapter and a public interface that extends ServiceMBean.

Comment: Yes, we can see that from the code that you posted, but what are you using those classes for?  We need to know that in order to recommend some Tomcat equivalent.

Comment: I've updated the question with substantially more code and context - thanks for helping!